# Can anyone provide an exact value for $\arcsin(0.3)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have already figured out an exact value using integration and basic geometry. I was wondering if there's a very elegant way to evaluate it.

Let in right angled  $\triangle ABD$ , lengths of hypotenuse AD ,base AB and height BD be 10,$\sqrt{91}$ and 3 respectively. Let B be the origin of a Cartesian co-ordinate system.

[image: Here's the image]

Then $\angle A$ = $\arcsin{(3/10)}=arcsin{0.3}$

Now, Area of circular segment ACD = Area of $\triangle$ABD + Area of BCD .

$\implies$ $\frac{\angle A}{2}\times10^2$ = $\frac{\sqrt{91}\times3}{2}$ + $\int_0^{(10-\sqrt{91})}\sqrt{10^2-(\sqrt{91}+x)^2}.dx $

$\implies 50\times\angle A = \frac{3\sqrt{91}}{2} + \frac{{[(9-x^2-2x\sqrt{91})^{3/2}]_{0}}^{(10-\sqrt{91})}}{-3(x+\sqrt{91})} $

$\implies \angle A = \frac{3\sqrt{91}}{100} + \frac{{[(9-x^2-2x\sqrt{91})^{3/2}]_{0}}^{(10-\sqrt{91})}}{-150(x+\sqrt{91})} $

$\implies arcsin{0.3} = \frac{3\sqrt{91}}{100} + \frac{{[(9-x^2-2x\sqrt{91})^{3/2}]_{0}}^{(10-\sqrt{91})}}{-150(x+\sqrt{91})} $

Comment: I have already figured out an exact value using integration and basic geometry. I was wondering if there's a very elegant way to evaluate it.

Comment: @DardaulHoque It would help if you explained your method, at the very least, so that we don't tell you what you've already done.

Comment: i think $$\arcsin(3/10)$$ is a transcendental number

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think the real thing to consider is whether $\arcsin(3/10)/\pi$ is transcendental

Comment: @DardaulHoque Also, what exactly do you mean by an "exact value"?  Do you mean "find $\arcsin(0.3)$ to a lot of decimal places", or do you mean "find a closed form expression in terms of constants like $\pi$ evaluating to $\arcsin(0.3)$"?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom  I meant the later one.

Comment: @DardaulHoque Then it would also be helpful if you could include your answer for the exact value.

Comment: Yeah okay. I am new to this place and having a hard time typing the maths. That's why I didn't include my answer.

Comment: @DardaulHoque okay, well, I think you're going to have to try to "type the maths" for your result before you get any answers

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: As mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals) Niven's theorem and Baker's theorem together imply that $\arcsin(3/10)$ cannot be an algebraic multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(10-sqrt(91))+sqrt(10%5E2-(sqrt(91)%2Bx)%5E2)dx) suggests that there is a mistake in your computations